# Push notification not receiving on iphone

Tags: php, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using **[this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)** to learn push notification.

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '1675ba8bb005740bb514222227f861c30230a81e6eed6bb6b8f353c57831341d';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '111134';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 $ctx = stream_context_create();
 stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
 stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

 if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

 echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) .  $payload;

 // Send it to the server
 $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
 echo 'result =' . $result. PHP_EOL;
if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

 // Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I also configure app for push notification. After configuring for push i also recreate provisioning  profiles, old delete one, install new profile. 
I run app it gives me device id and then i connect both server sandbox and production to send push notification with their relative push profiles but still i am not able to receive push notification on my device.

I also install ipusher on my device and check push notification. they are coming from that application.

One strange thing i notice is that i change my application identifier and use any other app id then device token remain same

Now my problem is I am not receiving the push notification on my device.

---

The problem is not in my profiles. May be the error is php code that i am using because when i use the easy apns on remote server then it sends push notifications.
The notifications received time was 6 to 7 hours. I think this is due to network problem on my device side.
But now it is working fine after 2 days on production profile. Now notification take no time for delivering on my device but it is taking 30 sec to 5 minutes on some devices.

---

There can be one more problem if you are not receiving push notifications on your device from other apps too, then you should check your DNS for the connection.

Comment: This is server side implementation part what about the iphone application part. U can check this tutorial http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services                                             http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Comment: i follow the raywenderlich for iphone implementation. for getting the device token

Comment: The problem is not in my profiles. May be the error is php code that i am using because when i use the easy apns on remote server then it sends push notifications. The notifications received time was 6 to 7 hours. I think this is due to network problem on my device side. But the now it is working fine after 2 days on production profile. Now notification take no time for delivering on my device but it is taking 30 sec to 5 minutes on some devices.

Comment: Can u tell me in which class u have written ur push notification delegate methods.

Comment: I wrote them in Application delegate class

Comment: A blog - https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/ - works great for our case. We have been using this method since it's release and had no issues so far.

Comment: I just now when i use my above code then push notification is not delivered. When i use easy apns on remote server then it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i finally got my Problem. The problem is not in code actually the problem is in Wrong DNS Value set in my iphone. Iphone automatically place ip of my router for DNS field. Now i give the DNS value of my service provider then it works fine. Now I am receiving Push messages As soon as i sent them.

**I Hope it helps others.**

Answer (score 7):

First make sure that you're using:

- The application is compiled with debug/release provision
- your keychain has the devlopment/production push notification certificate

then use the following code (been tested both dev & production)

```
<?php
// Comment these lines in production mode
ini_set('display_errors','on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);


// Apns config

// true - use apns in production mode
// false - use apns in dev mode
define("PRODUCTION_MODE",false);

$serverId = 1;
$serverName = 'my-server-domain.com';

if(PRODUCTION_MODE) {
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
} else {
$apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
}

$apnsPort = 2195;
if(PRODUCTION_MODE) {
// Use a development push certificate 
$apnsCert = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/apns/apns-dominos-development.pem';
} else {
// Use a production push certificate 
$apnsCert = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/apns/apns-dominos-production.pem';
}


// --- Sending push notification ---

// Insert your device token here 
$device_token = "<dc6127d8 dc6127d8 dc6127d8 dc6127d8 dc6127d8 dc6127d8 dc6127d8    dc6127d8>"; // Some Device Token


// Notification content

$payload = array();

//Basic message
$payload['aps'] = array(
'alert' => 'testing 1,2,3..', 
'badge' => 1, 
'sound' => 'default',
);
$payload['server'] = array(
'serverId' => $serverId,
 'name' => $serverName
);
// Add some custom data to notification
$payload['data'] = array(
'foo' => "bar"
);
$payload = json_encode($payload);

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'passphrase', "");


$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error,      $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);


$deviceToken = str_replace(" ","",substr($device_token,1,-1));
echo $deviceToken;
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '',      $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);


//socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);

?>
```

Comment: What are you doing in this line? and why?
$deviceToken = str_replace(" ","",substr($device_token,1,-1));

Comment: removing the spaces and the "<" prefix and  ">"  suffix. 
The device token is alphanumeric, no spaces or other characters

Answer (score 2):

Implement the feedback service on server side and also check on server side that within how much duration all the device token are send to APNS.
From feedback service atleast u will come to know that how much devices had received ur notification. 
If all the device token are send one by one to the APNs and the APNs does'nt send any list through feedback service then u cannot handle the duration to receive notification on devices.

Answer (score 1):

Check your push notification certificate. is certificate was associate with any private key?

If no then please recreate push notification certificate with appropriate private key which are generated from your key chain.

Please take a look at the below Tutorial:

[Apple Push Notification Tutorial:](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services)

thanks,

MinuMaster

Answer (score 1):

Use UrbanAirShip. In my opinion it's the best server side solution since it includes Push-alike notifications for Android (C2DM) and Blakberry too.

Try finding differences between these to files and understand them. Might be a solution to your problem. Here's my code:

```
<?php

$message = 'Hello'; // $_GET or $_POST
$badge = 3; // int
$sound = 'default'; // string - sound name
$development = true; // boolean

$payload = array();
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message, 'badge' => intval($badge), 'sound' =>    $sound);
$payload = json_encode($payload);

$apns_url = NULL; // Set Later
$apns_cert = NULL; // Set Later
$apns_port = 2195;

if($development)
{
    $apns_url = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
    $apns_cert = '/path/apns.pem'; // relative address to an App Specific Certificate     file 
}
else
{
    $apns_url = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
    $apns_cert = '/path/cert-prod.pem';
}

$stream_context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl','local_cert',$apns_cert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://'.$apns_url.':'.$apns_port,$error,$error_string,2,STREAM_CLIENT    _CONNECT,$stream_context);

//  You will need to put your device tokens into the $device_tokens array yourself
$device_tokens = array(); // tokens!!!

foreach($device_tokens as $device_token)
{
    $apns_message = chr(0).chr(0).chr(32).pack('H*',str_replace('    ','',$device_token)).chr(0).chr(strlen($payload)).$payload;
    fwrite($apns, $apns_message);
}

@socket_close($apns);
@fclose($apns);
?>
```