# EasyAPNS delivered the message but not received on iOS device

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I'm using [EasyAPNS](http://www.easyapns.com) as PHP server script to send Push Notifications to iOS devices.

It worked perfectly in development using Apple **Development** Push Notifications Certificate, but when switched to **Distribution** it set the message as "delivered" but never received on iOS devices downloaded from App Store!

I have tested Apple **Distribution** Push Notifications Certificate along with my app downloaded from the App Store using this [Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132664/push-notification-not-receiving-on-iphone/8225789#8225789) and it worked perfectly! So the problem is not from my distribution certificate nor from my app, it's somewhere in EasyAPNS scripts and settings but I have no idea where is it and how to fix it!

Comment: Did you use a Ad-Hoc Distribution Provisioning profile, and a production APNS certificate? Also try APNSPHP, it's more advanced than this little script. https://github.com/duccio/ApnsPHP

Answer (score 0):

Check if your using the right servers.

In your testing using that script, was development set to false? Or true depending on which example your using. Check if either of these result in the correct use of the production server.

`$development = true; // boolean`

Answer (score 0):

I found the bloody reason :)

The payload in `apns_messages`.`message` column was not inserted as a complete payload format due to a long message used, so the content of the message field was like the below:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"\u064a\u0627 \u0639\u0644\u064a \u0623\u0646\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0644\u064a \u064a\u0627 \u0639\u0644\u064a \u0623\u0646\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0648\u0644\u064a \u064a\u0627 \u0639\u0644\u064a \u0623\u0646\u062a \u0627\u0644\u0648\u064
```

So the change I made was to make sure use a very short message to make sure EasyAPNS insert a complete payload message format in `apns_messages`.`message` column, so the content of the field is like the below:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"\u064a\u0648\u062c\u062f \u0625\u0639\u0644\u0627\u0646 \u062c\u062f\u064a\u062f \u0645\u0646 \u062e\u062f\u0645\u0629 \u0628\u0644\u063a\u0646\u064a","badge":5,"sound":"alarm.caf"},"module":"messages","id":"28"}
```